# How to enter commands in Minecraft via remote keyboard

Tags: xbox-one, windows-10, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to enter commands in the Bedrock Edition of Minecraft on an XBox One, but I want to use the keyboard on my Windows 10 machine so I can paste commands in bulk.  (I'm trying to clear out a large area using the /fill command).  I seem to recall doing this at one point right after the Bedrock Edition came out, but now I can't remember how.

I have tried both the XBox app on Windows 10 in streaming mode, which seems to ignore my keyboard input, and XBox One Glass, which only listens to "A", "B", "X", and "Y" in remote mode.

Answer (score 1):

When streaming from the XBox One to Windows 10, hit the appropriate button on the controller to bring up the chat/console bar.  On my system it is the right "arrow" on the left side of the controller.  Then immediately hit "A" to edit the command.  This should immediately pop up a dialog box on the Windows box that a command can be entered or pasted.  (Sometimes this window does not get focus so you may need to click on it to focus it.)  If it does not pop this box up, try rebooting the XBox (make sure you go through the green logo screen) and/or Windows.  In my case that was the extra step needed to get it to work.